# update vcap env from application

Tags: java, node.js, cloud-foundry

is there a way in cf to update the vcap env `port` for service by code from my application, lets say I want to change the `port` to `12345` 
e.g.

```
{
 "VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "mongodb": [
   {
    "credentials": {
     "dbname": "ztmvvvmtrz",
     "hostname": "13.15.241.29",
     "password": "abzArl7AsssseKpi",
     "port": "22241",
```

while trying the `cf set-env` its update the `user provided env` and wasn't able to help...
some example on `java / node.js` will by great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly which information you're looking to change here, but values in environment variables like `VCAP_SERVICES`, `VCAP_APPLICATION`, `PORT` and anything starting with `CF_` like `CF_INSTANCE_PORT`, `CF_INSTANCE_PORTS` and/or `CF_INSTANCE_IP` are all provided for you by the platform.  They are effectively static.  Changing them will not do anything.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that they are ephemeral. If you did successfully change them in the environment, the next time the app gets restarted, the variables would be overwritten.